# How to assign to a slice range?

Tags: rust, slice, assign

I have a mutable slice, and I want to replace its prefix if it equals a certain slice.

I tried this:

```rust
let len = prefix.len();

if slice.starts_with(prefix) {
    slice[.. len - 1] = subst;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9724b10cb14671625024136c58a678e4)

However,

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[{integer}]` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         slice[.. len - 1] = *subst;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

(Let's forget about the other type error in the playground; in my code, I have proper slices instead of arrays.)

I understand this as saying "The slices might have different length, so you cannot do this".

However, how can I do this when I explicitly checked that the lengths are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut), something like this:

```rust
let len = prefix.len();
if slice.starts_with(prefix) {
    let (left, _right) = slice.split_at_mut(len);
    left.copy_from_slice(subst);
}
```

There is also explanation about this specific problem here: [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice)

---

**Edit:**
As Jmb stated in a comment, `split_at_mut()` is not needed:

```
let len = prefix.len();
if slice.starts_with(prefix) {
    slice[..len].copy_from_slice(subst);
}
```

Comment: No need for `split_at_mut`, [`copy_from_slice` can be used directly: `slice[.. len - 1].copy_from_slice (subst)`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7fb92daeb8dd49ae0fd5f61fd13acec4)

Comment: @Jmb: indeed it's not needed; edited my answer